# How to support comparison `<` and `>` operators for a Python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, comparison-operators

I have this code:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point((self.x ** 2) + (other.x ** 2), (self.y ** 2) + (other.y ** 2), (self.z ** 2) + (other.z ** 2))

    def __str__(self):
        return f'x: {self.x}, y: {self.y}, z: {self.z}'

pt1 = Point(3, 4, -5)
pt2 = Point(-4, 1, 3)

pt3 = pt1 + pt2

print(pt1 == pt2)
```

Now I want to change `==` in the last line to `>` or `<`, but this error was raised:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Point' and 'Point'

Answer (score 2):

These are the so-called "rich comparison" methods.

```py
object.__lt__(self, other)
object.__le__(self, other)
object.__eq__(self, other)
object.__ne__(self, other)
object.__gt__(self, other)
object.__ge__(self, other)
```

> The correspondence between operator symbols and method names is as follows:

- `x<y` calls `x.__lt__(y)`
- `x<=y` calls `x.__le__(y)`
- `x==y` calls `x.__eq__(y)`
- `x!=y` calls `x.__ne__(y)`
- `x>y` calls `x.__gt__(y)`
- `x>=y` calls `x.__ge__(y)`.

### Reference

- [docs.python/datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__add__#object.__lt__)